# Open all files with a partial name in subfolders - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open all files with names ending with ToDo.xlsx, by doing a loop that goes through all subfolders.

I found this loop in another post in StackOverflow, but it takes too much time when there are a lot of files (~35k in my case) :

```
Public Sub NonRecursiveMethod()
    Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set queue = New Collection
    queue.Add fso.GetFolder("your folder path variable") 'obviously replace

    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set oFolder = queue(1)
        queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
        '...insert any folder processing code here...
        For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
            queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
        Next oSubfolder
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            '...insert any file processing code here...
        Next oFile
    Loop
End Sub
```

My processing code is :

```
If InStr(oFile.Name,"ToDo"= <> 0 Then Workbooks.Open Filename:=oSubfolder & oFile
```

Is there a way to put this condition in the for loop, in order to minimize the processing time ?

Thank you

Comment: is it the opening of files with 'ToDo' that's taking the time, or the searching through all subfolders?

Comment: Searching for all files through all subfolders

Comment: so is the question 'how to improve performance in looping through all subfolders'? not sure how a recursive method performance compares with this.. anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

In stead of the `For each` loop, try if the following lop is faster:

```
filename = Dir(oFolder.Name & "\*ToDo.xlsx")
While (filename <> "")
    ' processing... Full name is oFolder.Name & "\" & filename
    filename = Dir
Wend
```