# How to Copy Data from the Contents of a set of files matching a naming convention in a specified folder to their matching rows in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a folder with many files, some ending with "*_todaysvalues.csv"
They are a simple two-cell sheet where A1 is a Name and B1 is their Score - Like:
A1: Jerry 
B1: 528

I have another sheet where cell Range C16:C56 holds the names that I need to match to the A1 cell in the previous file, and I need to insert the value in the range D16:D56.

I need to go through every file in the folder ending with "*_todaysvalues.csv". 
I'm still a bit new to VBA and am at a bit of a loss as to where to start... Any guidance is *greatly* appreciated!!

Comment: CSV files are text files that are delimited.  "Comma Separated Values".  In other words, the file would read "Jerry, 528" on one line, and "Jane, 621" on the next line, and so on and so forth.  You can think of them as cells, but they're not actually cells.  You can read them one line at a time and use a split function to put them into a small array, which allows you to search any sheet for those names.  To go through all the files, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981601/open-all-files-with-a-partial-name-in-subfolders-vba

Comment: Personally I like using delimited text files to store data because it is more efficient than storing an entire Excel Spreadsheet with the data on it.  You can get as complex as you like, rows and columns per se, and use any delimiter.  I like the pipe character because it's never used.  ie "John|Jerry|Jill|June|Jennifer".  You read that line into a variable "aLine" like "Line Input #fileNum, dataLine" and then aLine = split(dataLine,"|").  You will have an array of 5 names.  aLine(1) = "John" aLine(2) = "Jerry" , etc.